# In Python what's the best way to emulate Perl's __END__?

Tags: python

Am I correct in thinking that that Python doesn't have a direct equivalent for Perl's `__END__`?

```
print "Perl...\n";

__END__
End of code. I can put anything I want here.
```

One thought that occurred to me was to use a triple-quoted string. Is there a better way to achieve this in Python?

```
print "Python..."

"""
End of code. I can put anything I want here.
"""
```

Comment: Why do you need it in the first place?

Comment: Just an added convenience -- nothing more. I realize I can comment out the end of the file, of course.

Comment: "an added convenience" for what?  What does this make "convenient"?  What are you planning to do with this extra end-of-the-file comment block?

Comment: `__END__` is useful for many things, I've used it for long form documentation at the end, or as a place to throw a copy of a block of code if doing a major refactor, and I use it all the time on my "scratchpad" file where I do small code tests.  finish a test, slap `__END__` on top, and onto the next test.  That way the file keeps a running history of what I've worked on.

Comment: In python, documentation either goes in the docstrings at the top of the file/class/method/function, or in dedicated project documentation; tests go into tests.py or a tests directory; code history goes into version control.  Throwing all that under `__END__` sounds pretty hideous to me.

Comment: I use `__END__` in tests sometimes.  The use case is braindumping code, and then gradually getting it to compile and pass.  As the top starts to compile, you move `__END__` down a test case or two, and then work on those... and then repeat the process.  If you are using `git snapshot-watch`, it's all "version controlled" anyway.  `__END__` just saves you some typing and munging.

Comment: I've seen `__END__` used where someone wanted to include data in the executable itself.  I.e: the file is an python script and yaml file.  I know this is considered bad practice.  However, "why the #&%! would you want to do that?" isn't an answer.

Comment: Great, logical, sensible question FMc, thank you for asking it.

Comment: In vim I type ´Ctrl+v G I # Esc Esc´

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The triple-quote form you suggested will still create a python string, whereas Perl's parser simply ignores anything after `__END__`. You can't write:

```
"""
I can put anything in here...
Anything!
"""
import os
os.system("rm -rf /")
```

Comments are more suitable in my opinion.

```
#__END__
#Whatever I write here will be ignored
#Woohoo !
```

Comment: @Lott: You can put anything after perl's `__END__`, including perl code, more `__END__` tokens, literally anything.. You cannot put odd number of tripple quotes in the python tripple quoted string (unless you remember to escape it). If you put even number of tripple quotes and some python code, it will be executed.

Comment: Far clearer example than the previous version of this answer.

Comment: "Perl's parser simply ignores anything after `__END__`". Not really. The `DATA` file handle can access everything after `__END__`.

Comment: @AlanHaggaiAlavi The DATA file handle is not using Perl's parser, so yes, really. Once `__END__` or ` __DATA__` is seen by the parser, it's done. It makes note of the position and sets the seek point there so that DATA can read from that point on.

Answer (score 22):

The

```
__END__
```

block in perl dates from a time when programmers had to work with data from the outside world and liked to keep examples of it in the program itself.

Hard to imagine I know.

It was useful for example if you had a moving target like a hardware log file with mutating messages due to firmware updates where you wanted to compare old and new versions of the line or keep notes not strictly related to the programs operations ("Code seems slow on day x of month every month") or as mentioned above a reference set of data to  run the program against. Telcos are an example of an industry where this was a frequent requirement.

Lastly Python's cult like restrictiveness seems to have a real and tiresome effect on the mindset of its advocates, if your only response to a question is "Why would you want to that when you could do X?" when X is not as useful please keep quiet++.

Comment: When "there is only one way to do it" sometimes there isn't any way to do it.

Comment: Python is a lovely language but its design philosophy sometimes crosses the boundary between innovative and reactionary.

Answer (score 6):

What you're asking for does not exist.
Proof: http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg156396.html

A simple solution is to escape any " as \" and do a normal multi line string -- see official docs: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

( Also, atexit doesn't work: http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg156364.html )

Answer (score 2):

Hm, what about `sys.exit(0)` ? (assuming you do `import sys` above it, of course)

As to why it would useful, sometimes I sit down to do a substantial rewrite of something and want to mark my "good up to this point" place.

By using `sys.exit(0)` in a temporary manner, I know nothing below that point will get executed, therefore if there's a problem (e.g., server error) I know it **had to** be above that point.

I like it slightly better than commenting out the rest of the file, just because there are more chances to make a mistake and uncomment something (stray key press at beginning of line), and also because it seems better to insert 1 line (which will later be removed), than to modify X-many lines which will then have to be un-modified later.

But yeah, this is splitting hairs; commenting works great too... assuming your editor supports easily commenting out a region, of course; if not, `sys.exit(0)` all the way!

Comment: The problem with `sys.exit(0)` is everything below that is still parsed by the Python interpreter and a *SyntaxError* is raised if it doesn't have valid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I use `__END__` all the time for multiples of the reasons given. I've been doing it for so long now that I put it (usually preceded by an `exit('0');`), along with `BEGIN {}` / `END{}` routines, in by force-of-habit. It is a shame that Python doesn't have an equivalent, but I just comment-out the lines at the bottom: extraneous, but that's about what you get with *one way to rule them all* languages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way (but not the only one) I use `__END__` in Perl, now that I am doing comparative analysis of Perl versus Python3, particularly re regex and most important, debugging regex. I first write the Perl version of whatever I am testing. I place two shebangs at the top, the first with warnings enabled (-w), the second invoking the debugger (-wd), and I switch between them as needed. I added two more shebangs for Python3, the second using Python's debugger (-m pdb). To run Python3 code I place the Python3 shebangs at the top, the topmost whichever flavor of Python I wish to run and using vim's mark line feature for block commands, place a single # in front of each Perl line. To revert to Perl, shuffle the shebangs and uncomment one # using a block command in vim. Works great! Take it for a test drive, anyone comparing Perl against Python.

So far, in my analysis, in Python3 I really like `print(p.groupindex)` where p is a compiled regex, to examine the mapping between group names and numbers, while in Perl I prefer `__END__` and the regex debugging modules. Also, there is mod_perl but no longer a mod_python, and probably never will be again. I'm not big on OOP, prefer functional programming for which either is suitable. Of course, if I was into OOP, my choice would be Python3 for its clean multiple inheritance model. Just IMHO, after 30+ years with Perl. To be honest, it took a long time to become truly proficient with Perl but Python is quicker to learn, but perhaps that's because I really am proficient in Perl and C. As always, your mileage will vary...

Answer (score -6):

Python does not have a direct equivalent to this.

Why do you want it? It doesn't sound like a really great thing to have when there are more consistent ways like putting the text at the end as comments (that's how we include arbitrary text in Python source files. Triple quoted strings are for making multi-line strings, not for non-code-related text.)

Your editor should be able to make using many lines of comments easy for you.

Comment: Sometimes while you are writing code, it is useful to comment out a section of code that doesn't work yet, and have Perl pretend that the code doesn't exist.

Comment: Just because you can't think of a reason to use it, doesn't mean there isn't a reason.

Comment: @Brad, Commenting out code can be very precarious, and often indicates that someone is not properly using their editor or version control system. If someone does wish to comment out a big section of code still, any reasonable text editor makes this simple. What multiline strings do is not commenting at all, and I have seen this really cause problems for people who wrote code acting like they are.

Comment: You'll note I didn't claim there were no reasons; in fact I asked for the reason. Only by getting to the real problem can we get the optimal solution.

Comment: Why do -I- want this?

I want it because it is useful to have a block of text documenting the usage of the program within the program (it isn't worthy of it's own file) and I cannot seem to arrange a good way of telling the parser to just straight /IGNORE/ all of the characters it is never intended to interact with.

The __ END __ keyword, or at least terminating further scanning of syntax on an always reachable exit() call would be useful.

Comment: I've found __END__ quite useful.  Same with __DATA__.  I miss both of those in python.  Yes, I can manage without them, but they'd be handy for me to have.  I often have some data in text form that I want to throw a little DATA-reading script on top of.  It's quick & dirty.